Error en auditoria de sql server
Hola como va? cree una auditoria de sql server y una especificación de la misma pero cuando trato de verla no me visualiza nada el visor de sql server management studio y me aparece el siguiente error: "Ya se ha agregado el elemento. Clave en el diccionario: 'MNDO'  Clave agregada: 'MNDO' (Auditoria_DB_AdventureWorks)", alguien tiene idea que puede estar pasando, en el folder de destino de las auditorias se crean archivos .sqlaudit que si puedo visualizarlos correctamente con el comando sys.fn_get_audit_file




¿qué versión de SQL Server y del SSMS estás usando?

En la universidad donde doy clases los estudiantes encuentran este tipo de errores hasta que aplican el más reciente cumulative update a SQL Server. También recomendable para una mejore experiencia de usuario descargar SQL Server Management Studio en su versión más reciente.
Los errores que presenta SQL Server Auditing son precisamente viendo (View) de los logs de auditoria.
Otra recomendación dar permisos al folder donde estas alojando el archivo de auditoría al servicio de SQL Server.
